# How to get user command using discord webhook?

Tags: c#, discord, webhooks, discord.net

I know how to post message to discord channel using discord webhook but how to get command from user? like I ask discord user yes/no and get answer back from that user?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     Discord.Send("Message");
    }
    public class Discord
    {
        public static string lol = "weburl";
        public static string user = "name";

        public class Http
        {
            public static byte[] Post(string url, NameValueCollection pairs)
            {
                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                    return webClient.UploadValues(url, pairs);
            }
        }
        public static void Send(string content)
        {
            Http.Post(lol, new NameValueCollection()
            {
                {
                    "content", content
                },

                {
                    "username", user
                },

                {
                    "avatar_url", "link"
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, you do not appear to be using `Discord.Net` (although you included it in the tags).

If I understand your question correctly however, what you are asking is not possible. Webhooks are used solely for **output**. You can not get user responses/input via a webhook. If you need to interact with users within Discord you need to create a [Discord Bot Application](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and use [Discord's API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference) to send/receive messages.

There are a number of API wrappers available for C#

[Disqord](https://github.com/Quahu/Disqord)
[DSharpPlus](https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus)
[Discord.NET](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net)
[Remora.Discord](https://github.com/Nihlus/Remora.Discord)

Comment: Oh I thought it was possible

Comment: It's possible using Discords Interactions Endpoint URL. Discord added the ability to send all interaction commands (Slash, User, etc) to a specified endpoint for processing. That being said, I have not seen any code that actually leverages it.

https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#receiving-an-interaction